# IIS HTTP/S rewrite with SSL offloading non-standard local port

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, iis-8, arr

Ok, so I'm hitting a dead end.  Here is my scenario:

- IIS running sites on 80 and 443 - *external.foo.com* and *https://external.foo.com*
- A separate web service is running an app on port 801 on the same node - "web app3" .

I created a site in IIS for *external.foo.com/app3*.  I need all traffic coming to *http(s)://external.foo.com/app3* to be routed to the local port 801 with SSL offloading - so the connection from the client to IIS is SSL, but IIS's connection to the local service is http over port 801.

Here is my rule set on foo/app3 in IIS, but it's not working and I feel like I tried 1000 things that don't quite get me there.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP and HTTPS to local Port 801 w/ offloading" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
             <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
             <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
             </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://external.foo.com:801/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
          </rule>
       </rules>
 </rewrite>
```

I honestly think my issue lies in having to specify port 801 in the request, but I'm not familiar enough with this area to make heads or tails of this.  In a couple of my tests I've seen where both port 80 or 443 are being specified which will not get to app3.

I also tried the Server Farm/load balance route and rule, but honestly that just confused me more... At one point I could get all my other sites to redirect and loaded app3, but not app3!  Below is that rule:

```
<rewrite>
   <globalRules>
         <clear />
            <rule name="ARR_App3Proxy_loadbalance" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*external.foo.com/app3" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://App3Proxy/{R:0}" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
              </conditions>
         </rule>
    </globalRules>
</rewrite>
```

I'm a newb - helps pleash!

**Update:**

Ok, I have all sites being redirected to app3 now via HTTPS and it appears offloading is working fine using ARR.  Global rule is below.

```
<proxy enabled="true" />
        <rewrite>
            <globalRules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="ARR_App3Proxy_loadbalance" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://App3Proxy/{R:0}" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </globalRules>
        </rewrite>
```

Now I just need to target *external.foo.com/app3* specifically so my other IIS sites will be excluded from this... I'm researching and testing now, but any assistance will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Add a condition to check HOST header, and modify `url` in `match` to check only URLs of app3 instead.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you, I couldn't get that to work, but Im sure I'm doing it wrong.  Care to show me or explan in a bit more detail?